# Flask: getting random repeated flash messages when flash() is in @app.before_request

Tags: python, flask

When i use flash() in @app.before_request, I get what seems like a random number of repeated entries.  Refreshing the page over and over will give me between 1 and 4 repeated messages.

There aren't any redirects.

My code is simply:

```
   if app.config['INSTANCE'] == 'DEV':
       flash("This data is from the development DB")
```

Alternatively, I wasn't able to figure out how to access/modify the array of messages that flash() seems to append to other than in the template via get_flashed_messages().  Anyone know how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the list of waiting messages via `flashes = session.get('_flashes', [])`.  You can [view the code on Github](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/helpers.py#L342)

On the note of why you're getting a few messages flashing, it's because you're making multiple requests (but probably don't know it).  Your web-browser is probably asking for `favicon.ico` which is a request, so causes a flash, etc.  If you're running in debug mode, your console window will show all the requests being handled.  For example loading a simple flask example in Chrome causes this to show:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2013 16:35:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2013 16:35:05] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

One is my request to view the homepage, the other is Chrome asking for the favicon (and it being told it doesn't exist).