# Flask - duplicates flash messages

Tags: python, flask, duplicates, flash-message

I have problem with flask [`flash()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/) function, `get_flashed_messages()` always returns me duplicates.
I set flash for logout :

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You are logged out!', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

and in view I have:

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for type, message in messages %}
            <div class="callout {{ type }}">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Is it a flask bug? I have printed `messages` variable and this have more than 1 flash logout message, the count of messages is in range 1-3.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't accidentally sending multiple requests? Could you give us the output from running the Flask application?

Comment: You mean html??

Comment: The log from debug=True in your console after running `python <yourapp>.py`. You want to look out for any duplicate `GET` requests after refreshing your browser, as they'll probably be what's triggering the duplicate messages. It's most likely a missing resource, see related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240394/flask-getting-random-repeated-flash-messages-when-flash-is-in-app-before-req

Comment: Here is log, for the fifth time it is doubly http://snipet.co.uk/Qi/raw

Comment: Do you use some sort of layout.html as as a base template?

Comment: @StijnDiependaele yes, i use layout.html as base template, and [this](http://snipet.co.uk/uj/raw) is in layout.html