# Flask - One flash message will not go away, due to functools.wraps?

Tags: python, flask

I am building a simple flask webapp as part of [Harvard's CS50 Web Programming Course](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:HarvardX+CS50W+Web/course/) to learn web development.  I've successfully got user registration / log in / logout implemented, along with various message flashing to give the user feedback.

For some reason, the "Login Successful" flash message just won't go away after its displayed.  I've read the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/?highlight=flashing), and some useful posts like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/613m81/flash_messages_always_show_up/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240394/flask-getting-random-repeated-flash-messages-when-flash-is-in-app-before-req).  It seems like any route with the `@login_required` decorator can't get rid of the flashed message.

Fully working code is here: [GoodBookBadBook](https://github.com/kevinhynes/goodbookbadbook)

Here is the `application.py` file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, session, request, render_template, url_for, redirect, flash
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import functools

app = Flask(__name__)

DATABASE_URL = "postgres://xqmbmqkcvpavvs:17f6f6f690bb777e4d484e3ee441e3b4d8c88591d239a9beb49aca4599863b97@ec2-52-70-15-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfg72kp1ckutig"
app.config["DATABASE_URL"] = DATABASE_URL

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


def login_required(route_func):
    @functools.wraps(route_func)  # returns wrapper as route_func (?).
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"wrapper flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
        if "logged_in" in session:
            return route_func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash("You must log in to use GoodBookBadBook.", category="error")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrapper


@app.route("/")
def index():
    print(f"index flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    return render_template("index.html", logged_in=session.get("logged_in", False))


@app.route("/main")
@login_required
def main():
    print(f"main flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    return render_template("main.html", logged_in=session.get("logged_in", False))


@app.route("/books")
@login_required  # calls wrapper() with arguments to books().
def books():
    print(f"books flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    books = db.execute("SELECT * from Books").fetchall()
    return render_template("books.html", books=books, logged_in=session.get("logged_in", False))


@app.route("/books/<int:book_id>")
@login_required  # calls wrapper() with arguments to books().
def book(book_id):
    print(f"book flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    book = db.execute("SELECT * from Books WHERE id = :book_id", {"book_id": book_id}).fetchone()
    print(f"book() /books/book_id {book}", flush=True)
    return render_template("book.html", book=book, logged_in=session.get("logged_in", False))


@app.route("/authors")
@login_required  # calls wrapper() with arguments to authors().
def authors():
    print(f"authors flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    books = db.execute("SELECT * from Books").fetchall()
    return render_template("authors.html", books=books, logged_in=session.get("logged_in", False))


@app.route("/signup", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    username = request.form.get("username")
    pwd = request.form.get("pwd")
    repeat_pwd = request.form.get("repeat_pwd")
    print(f"signup flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if validate_registration(username, pwd, repeat_pwd):
            hash = generate_password_hash(pwd)
            db.execute("INSERT INTO Users(Username, Hash) VALUES (:username, :hash)",
                       {"username": username, "hash": hash})
            db.commit()
            flash("Registration successful.", category="success")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template("signup.html")


def validate_registration(username, pwd, repeat_pwd):
    existing_user = db.execute("SELECT * from Users WHERE Username = :username",
                               {"username": username}).fetchone()
    print(f"validate_registration flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    if existing_user:
        flash("Username unavailable.", category="error")
        return False
    if len(username) < 3:
        flash("Username must be at least 3 characters", category="error")
        return False
    if pwd != repeat_pwd:
        flash("Passwords do not match.", category="error")
        return False
    if len(pwd) < 3:
        flash("Password must be at least 3 characters.", category="error")
        return False
    return True


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    username = request.form.get("username")
    pwd = request.form.get("pwd")
    print(f"login flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    if request.method == "POST":
        existing_user = db.execute("SELECT * from Users WHERE Username = :username",
                                   {"username": username}).fetchone()
        if not existing_user:
            flash("No user found. Please sign up first.", category="error")
            return redirect(url_for('signup'))
        if not check_password_hash(existing_user.hash, pwd):
            flash("Incorrect password.", category="error")
            return
        else:
            session["logged_in"] = True
            flash("Login successful. Thank you for using GoodBookBadBook.", category="success")
            return redirect(url_for('main'))
    return render_template("login.html")


@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    print(f"logout flashes: {session.get('_flashes', [])}", flush=True)
    session.pop("logged_in", None)
    flash("You have successfully been logged out. Come back soon!", category="success")
    return render_template("logout.html", logged_in=session.get("logged_in", False))
```

Been stuck on this all day, any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:  I updated the git repo to remove all references to a timeout script.  I am not going to use a timeout script in the final code.**

EDIT 2: Here's a [30 second video of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvqjL.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

just delete the  block script from  `signup.html` and `main.html` and it will work

```
{% block scripts %}
{#  <script type="text/javascript">window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('success-msg').style.display='none';", 2000); </script>#}
{% endblock %}
```

in `Layout.html`  in `head` tag add for `sucess-msg` and `error-msg`

```
<head>
<script   type="text/javascript">window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('success-msg').style.display='none';", 2000); </script>
</head>
```

Being `layout.html` as your base Html page, you need to add all the common use script in that base file, which can be used in other files. ERROR is occurring because of this (render_template function, jinja internal caching, don't worry about that now)

Comment: That line is already commented out.  But I fully removed it and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: @marcus_afailius working fine for me, just uncomment those 2 line from both pages

Comment: Did you log in to the website?  You can use 'sss' as the username and password, or register first with whatever.  All the flash messages are working, the problem is that the "Login Successful" one doesn't go away.  If you go to the books or authors page after logging in, it's still there and it should not be.  I was playing the timeout to fix the problem, but it's a workaround and I'm trying to figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: @marcus_afailius updated solution. it is working now, i hadn't check those, thought you added script in each page pertaining to that, but little debugging get it through

Comment: I'm sorry that I left the timeout script in the code - I only had it there to play around.  I don't want to use it in the final code.  Anyway, I went ahead and placed the script in `layout.html`, and it still does not solve the problem.  Now even when I look up search queries, the books or authors list, "Login Successful" still appears as a flashed message.  It disappears after the timeout, but it shouldn't appear at all.

Comment: working fine for me, you need to remove block_script from each file and just add script tag in layout.html in header part  and remove {block_scipt} part from there

Comment: If you log in, and then click the books link, do you see the flashed message?  I removed all instances of the timeout script, except in `layout.html`, and I still see the "Login Successful" message.  Either way, I do not want to use a timeout script.  I want to understand why there is a problem in the first place.

Comment: @marcus_afailius check pull request in github , i have added the changes on which i am getting result

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but as I've mentioned in the 3 comments above: 1) I do not want to use a timeout script, and 2) the timeout script **does not** solve the problem.  See here: https://imgur.com/a/EBXjvw2